# Here is a piece of code from Automate the Boring Stuff

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
#! python3
# pw.py - An insecure password locker program.

PASSWORDS = {'email': 'F7minlBDDuvMJuxESSKHFhTxFtjVB6',
              'blog': 'VmALvQyKAxiVH5G8v01if1MLZF3sdt',
               'luggage': '12345'}

import sys, pyperclip

if len(sys.argv) < 2:
    print('Usage: py pw.py [account] - copy account password')
    sys.exit()

account = sys.argv[1] # first command line arg is the account name

if account in PASSWORDS:
    pyperclip.copy(PASSWORDS[account])
    print('Password for ' + account + ' copied to clipboard.')
else:
    print('There is no account named ' + account)
```

This is code from "Automate the boring stuff". The goal of the exercise is to run Python files from command prompt. I have already created the batch file and added it to PATH.

I entered "password (email)" in my Run dialog box but it always says "There is no account named email"

What I enter in the dialog box:
[image: What I enter in the dialog box]

What it displays:
[image: What it displays]

Could it be that I entered it in the wrong format or what?

Comment: Why are you putting `()` around the command line option?

Comment: My bad. Worked just fine without the brackets. Was following the syntax the author used. Am new to all this. I appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that you lose those `()` around email, and if that does not work then try running cmd and navigate to your `pw.py` folder. Once you are in that folder, type:

```
pw.py email
```

this should take the first argument as stated in your code `account = sys.argv[1]`